# django applying a style class based on a conditional

Tags: django, django-templates

I am displaying a list of images. 
If the user has uploaded an image, I want to keep its opacity 0.5 and in the list of images, the images uploaded by others should have full opacity. 
I have done it as follows, is there a better way to do it??

```
{% if request.user == obj.shared_by %}
       <div class="item-image" style="opacity:0.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50);"> 
          {% else  %}
          <div class="item-image"> 
          {% endif %}
        ......Some code here....
       </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I normally go for:

```
<div class="item-image{% if foo %} own-image{% endif %}">...</div>
```

but switching out the entire `div` tag may be more readable.

Either way I'd do the styling with another class, not with inline css.

Comment: Why I can't do this `<div class="item-image{% for foo in foos %} {% if foo %} own-image{% endif %} {% endfor %}">...</div>` why can't I use for loop inside of an element's attribute  ?

Comment: this should probably be a new question but that should work. the template language doesn't know or care about the semantics of the surrounding html

Answer (score 5):

I have added class on if condition by this way....

```html
<li class="nav-item {% if app_url == '/' %} active{% endif %}">
```